# Checking permission in Sonata Admin lists

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I need to disable downloading lists and also customize the query depending on user permission in Sonata Admin

This limits the list results based on Role

```
public function createQuery($context = 'list')
{
    $query = parent::createQuery($context);
    $security_context = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.context');
    $user = $security_context->getToken()->getUser();
    $staff = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getRepository('AppBundle:Staff')->findOneBy(array('user' => $user));
    if ($security_context->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')  && !$security_context->isGranted('ROLE_EXECUTIVE_ADMIN')) 
    {
        $query->andWhere($query->getRootAlias().'.store',':store');
        $query->setParameter('store', $staff->getStore());
    }
    return $query;
}
```

This should hide the download button based on permission

```
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{
    $collection->remove('delete')
    ->remove('create');
    $security_context = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.context');
    if ($security_context->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')  && !$security_context->isGranted('ROLE_EXECUTIVE_ADMIN')) 
    {
        $collection->remove('export');
    }
}
```

How can I achieve the intended obijectives because this implementation returns the error below:

```
The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL in . (which is being imported from "E:\www\project\app/config\routing.yml").
```

Answer (score 0):

After Symfony 2.6 *security.context* is deprecatedm now you should use  *security.authorization_checker* service: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements

Now its like this:

```
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{
    $collection->remove('delete')
               ->remove('create');
    $authorization_checker = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('authorization_checker');
    if ($authorization_checker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')  && !$authorization_checker->isGranted('ROLE_EXECUTIVE_ADMIN')) 
    {
        $collection->remove('export');
    }
}
```